# Event handling matplotlip python

Tags: python, events, matplotlib

I want to pick and draw points from a figure and stock their coordinations in array. Is that possible? If yes, can you help by just guiding me please and thanks for your help.

I have this example but it is drawing a line:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print('click', event)
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0])  # empty line
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to draw points instead of a line, you need to define a marker and optionally turn the line off:

```
line, = ax.plot([0], [0], marker="o", linestyle="")
```

The coordinates are already stored in the arrays `LineBuilder.xs` and `LineBuilder.xs` so you may just print them.

Complete example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        print(self.xs)
        print(self.ys)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0], marker="o", linestyle="") 
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great, in this case you may [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. You may also want to take the  [tour] to see how SO works in general.